# How to Implement multiple gateways for authorization C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC app and have been researching good practices for authentication and authorization and have found that it is good practice to not rely on a single gatekeeper.

However I have not been able to find any good resources on what a gatekeeper is, or any C# examples of using multiple gatekeepers.

Could someone please assist?

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648650.aspx#c05618429_006
See Authentication

Comment: so from where did you read the term 'gate keeper', the source should have put some light on it right ?

Comment: please have a look here http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/02/25/authorizenet-integration-using-aspnet/

Comment: @AppDeveloper Added my source

Comment: Did you read the link you posted?  Your own linked mentioned *Options include IIS Web permissions, NTFS permissions, ASP.NET file authorization (which applies only with Windows authentication), URL authorization, and principal permission demands*.  Gatekeeper in this instance pretty much sounds like multiple ways to limit Authorization, and not specifically multiple types of frameworks built in .Net (Although Forms Authentication is, but not mentioned).  No need to go crazy, a properly implemented Forms Authentication and good Systems Administrator should get you far.